What's the meaning of "nai gar"?
I was reading Plautus yesterday and I saw "nai gar" I thought it was a typo, but I remembered that could be a Greek word, then I Googled it. It was.I used the Google translate and the translation was "yes bro". I DON'T know anything about Greek.

Yes, it's Greek. The expression is ναὶ γάρ.
ναί is an adverb used to express affirmation, though LSJ's suggestion of 'yea' or 'verily' as a translation is probably a bit grandiloquent. It's also the origin of modern Greek's ναι 'yes'.
γάρ is a causal particle, often translated as 'because' or 'as', but depending on the context it can have a wide range of possible translations, including none at all. In this context its presence is idiomatic and not really amenable to literal interpretation; it's kind of like mais 'but' in French mais oui 'of course', lit. 'but yes'.
The combined expression ναὶ γάρ is post-Classical and non-literary, as you'd expect in Plautus; I would probably go with "yes, indeed" over "yes bro", as indeed the green and yellow for Pseudolus suggests.
It actually shows up a few times in Plautus. The manuscripts often (but not always) render Greek in Latin characters, and it can show up as nae gar, necar, negar, or even more mangled than that (in Pseudolus line 484, what is now generally taken to have been "καὶ τοῦτο ναὶ γάρ" becomes "cetuton kaito itone gars" in two of the Palatine manuscripts); modern editions will generally have it as proper Greek.

Do you mean pre- classical? Plautus was 254-184BC while Classical Latin started 75BC

@DanielT I mean post-Classical Greek.
